# How do i change directories on command prompt in runtime and then run another process?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C copy /b Image1.jpg + Archive.rar Image2.jpg";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

This will open/run the cmd.exe will hide the window and do the Arguments.
What i want to do is that it will run the cmd.exe then will go to:

```
D:\pipetest\pipetest\ffmpegx86
```

Will do another Arguments:

```
"rem ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -video_size 1280x720 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r 25 out.avi"
```

Then it will make the command start the process name: `Run`

I mean after it will make the arguments it will make `Run` like i'm typing Run and enter in the command prompt window.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run one process, then the other, or put the various commands you need to run in a batch file, and then run that.

Comment: But it newver launch it. I mean it's just open a new cmd prompt window and does nothing. If i do it manual when the pipes code is in console application and then i manual make the arguments and type Run "Run" it's working. But through windows forms project i added a new class and call it through Form1 button click event it dose nothing. why is that ?

Comment: I created this thread question later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674873/how-do-i-use-pipes-and-also-how-do-i-use-a-process-to-run-a-process